# Install linux bash script from windows to a remote linux system

Tags: linux, bash, putty

I have a set of bash scripts I want to install to a remote linux system. I have created a batch file to be run on the windows host system using plink and putty to transfer the files to the linux system. But Plink is not able to run the install script, which actually schedules the scripts in to crontab it gives "Permission denied error" as chmod command is not run. Is there any work around this? 
The command used to send files to the linux box

```
 "c:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\pscp" -pw passwd *.sh   user@192.168.1.1:/mnt/capture/logs/
```

The command used to run the script

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe" -ssh -pw passwd -noagent user@192.168.1.1   /mnt/capture/logs/script.sh
```

The script.sh file is as follows

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo /mnt/md0/capture/logs/install.sh
```

The plink command gives script.sh : Permission denied.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? For example, what exactly are you running? Can you post the commands, or an example of them? What fails? How do I reproduce the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

call the chmod before you invoke it:

```
plink -ssh -pw password -noagent user@192.168.1.1 "sh -c 'cd /mnt/capture/logs && chmod a+x *.sh && ./script.sh'"
```

If you have edited the script in a Windows text editor, make sure they are saved in Unix file format so that you do not have CR-NL line endings.

Also, your script uses `sudo` -- is user nethawk listed in the sudoers file? Are you expected to enter your password?

Comment: I want the user to enter the sudo password.

Comment: You'll probably need to use something like expect to build in that level of interactivity. You won't get it with `ssh user@host command`

Comment: the bat file gives me error "sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified"

Comment: That's a clue: hunt around for a windows-and-plink-compatable askpass program

Comment: Got it -ssh -t asked for the sudo password.. and all done :) cheers mate .. thanks for help